# Individually labeling plots generated by Map

Tags: plotting

I understand that this has been asked before, but none of the solutions are working for me:

I'm plotting a function for many different values of a variable, z, using `Map`. I have the `Evaluate->True` tag, and my plots are appearing as different colors, but try as I might I can't seem to get the labels for more than the first line.

Here is what I have:

```
zlist = Table[z, {z, zmin, zmax, zincrement}]

Plot[Map[function[x, #] & , zlist], {x, 1, 10}, 
 Evaluated -> True, PlotLegends -> zlist]
```

It generates the expected plot with each line in a different color, but with only one label! This shouldn't be happening as far as I have been able to determine. Not sure what's going on.

edit - i've been linked to a solution: If you manually wrap the Map function in Evaluate[], rather than using Evaluate->True, it works. Feels like a bug, but just in case anyone runs into it that's a simple workaround.

Comment: I'm gonna report this as a bug, works fine in version 9

Comment: @Jason, as a reminder: `Evaluated` is undocumented; *caveat emptor* and all that jazz. ;)

Comment: Well, I know what reply I'll get on the bug report now then :-D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it's happening, but replacing the `Evaluated->True` with `Evaluate` in front of your `Map` fixes the situation:

```
zlist = {1, 2, 3};
Plot[Evaluate@Map[Sin[x #] &, zlist], {x, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> zlist]
```

[image]